# How to get youtube video's geo information via google api develper?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I want to get the geospatial location of a Youtube video to do some research. How to get youtube video's geo-information via google API developer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get geolocation of videos unless you are the owner of the video. But you can search for videos around a specific location.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#location
https://github.com/youtube/geo-search-tool

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, I am so happy that you answered my question. These days I am keeping finding the how to get the geolocation of video, and I found a website, https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java could you  please open this URL and search GeoRssWhere location = videoEntry.getGeoCoordinates(); on your page. I am not sure this can be used to get the location information. Thanks so much.

Comment: API v2 is turned down.

Comment: Yes, API v2 has turned down, I know. SoI am considering if API v3 inherits the same function from v2. I am not sure and I am keeping figuring out because it is really important for my work. If you have the clear answer, could you tell me. Thank you very very very much.

Comment: @DongQin This functionality is not available in v3 of the API.  It was deprecated without a replacement.

Comment: @JAL thanks for your reply. I referred to this website https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos and found: :The JSON structure below shows the format of a videos resource: there is something indicates  "locationDescription": string,
    "location": {
      "latitude": double,
      "longitude": double,
      "altitude": double
    }, you can open this url and search location and will locate this information. so i am still confused if I can get the geo location of a video by this joson file. thank you very much.